# Redirect visitor based on referral URL

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect visitors to one page on my website if they have come from a certain URL and another if they don't.

```
<?
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ( $referer != "http://URL1" ) {
  header('Location: page1');
  exit;
 } else {
  header('Location: page2');
 }
?>
```

Whatever referrer I come to the page on it goes to page 1 and never to page 2. I have used this code in a index.php file so its the first page the visitor is directed too.

Comment: Is that the whole error message?

Comment: ...and is that the whole code? _Error redirecting_ doesn't sound like a regular PHP error.

Comment: Note that `if ( $referer != "http://URL1" || "http://URL2" ) {` doesn't do what you think it does. I recommend using a `switch()` block instead.

Comment: I would recommend `in_array()` instead

Comment: @PeeHaa: how would you recommend `in_array()` in this case?

Comment: `if (!in_array($referer, ['http://URL1', 'http://URL2'], true)) {`

Comment: there seems to be a problem with how i am identifying the referrer at the moment it only goes to page 1 whatever the referrer is, just using one referrer link

Comment: @Luke14: is that the whole code on that php page?

Comment: Check your variables. Place `var_dump($referrer);die();` after you set its value. What does `$referrer` give you in the case where you think it should go to page2?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** alright, so from the discussions, it seems that the reason why your code won't work is that you are checking the referer string using the "now-www" url, while the actual referer string has "www" in the url. Please, make sure to use the exact referer string. Otherwise, if you are redirecting based on the `hostname` of the referer you can use the updated answer below.

```
<?php
$referer = str_replace("www.", "", parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST));
switch($referer) {
  case "johnchow.com":
    header("Location: page1");
    break;
  case "domain2.com":
    header("Location: page2");
    break;
  default:
    header("Location: page3");
}
exit;
```

Comment: but how do i refer traffic who are not from either of the two URL's?

Comment: updated the answer.. when the traffic is not from any of the urls, the  redirect in `default:` case will be used (in this case: `page3`

Comment: okay this works but again its constantly going to the default and i dont know why, this is i am identifying a URL `case "http://johnchow.com":` also i didn't down vote you

Comment: In that case, please dump the `$referer` variable and make sure that it is not empty, or use the updated answer :P

Comment: the referrer isnt empty, however its still skipping the case with the referring URL and going straight to the default :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43555/discussion-between-stoic-and-luke14)

Answer (score 0):

For starters change this to

```
if ( $referer != "http://URL1" || $referer != "http://URL2" )
```

Secondly, page1 and page2 are likely giving the error because they are invalid. Include the path and extension. For example:

```
header('Location: http://www.yourlocation/page1.php')
```

Looks like the error has been clarified...

Comment: it is not necessary to provide the full URL for the location header, and it can instead be a relative URL.

Comment: @Stoic No it can not according to the spec.

Comment: @PeeHaa: can you point me to a reference? I am not aware of this. Also, the code will, however, still work, if I am correct?

Comment: [RFC 2616 (a.k.a. the spec): "The field value consists of a single absolute URI."](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)

Comment: The original post stated Error redirecting. Seems like qualifying your url is a good place to start to rule it out as a problem. Why the downvote?

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the spec :)
@mseifert: if you will edit the post, I will be able to remove my downvote.